# LoadLibrary Dll injector taking path input and "scrambling it"

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, dll-injection

I've created a GUI DLL injector in QT Creator using the MinGW 32bit compiler and keep getting this reoccurring issue where I'll click inject and it won't inject the DLL but it will however scramble my DLL path.

Example: [Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyHaj.png)

- The first path is the DLL after converting it the correct type
- Last DLL is the DLL after the process
- The address is the address where the DLL is located in the target process
- 0 is GetLastError()

The code DLL path conversion:

```
QString fileInput = ui->filesCmb->currentText();    //gets dll
dllPath = fileInput.toStdString().c_str();    //converts dll to string
qDebug() << dllPath << "\n";
```

The injection Process code:

```
QString methodChosen = ui->methodCmb->currentText();
QString targetProcess = ui->processTxt->text();
const wchar_t* tgtProc = (const wchar_t*)targetProcess.utf16();

if (methodChosen == "Manual Map") {
    ui->statusTxt->setPlainText("Method not added[" + methodChosen + "]");

} else if (methodChosen == "LdrLoadDLL") {
    ui->statusTxt->setPlainText("Method not added[" + methodChosen + "]");

} else {
    ui->statusTxt->setPlainText("File input: " + fileInput + "\n" + "Method: " + methodChosen + "\n" + "Target Process: " + targetProcess + "\n" + "Dll path: " + dllPath + "\n");
    DWORD pid = getPid(tgtProc);
    dwordToQstring = QString::number(pid);

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);
    if (!pHandle || pHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        ui->statusTxt->setPlainText("Couldn't get handle[" + dwordToQstring + "]");
    }

    LPVOID pDllPath = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);  // allocate memeory within our target process to fit our dll


    if (pDllPath != nullptr) {
        WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, pDllPath, (LPVOID)dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0); //writes our dll to the allocated memory
        HANDLE hLoad = CreateRemoteThread(pHandle, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"), pDllPath, 0, 0); //creates a thread in the target process to allow out code to run


        if (hLoad != nullptr) {
            WaitForSingleObject(hLoad, INFINITE);   //maybe waits for our dll code to execute?
            ui->statusTxt->setPlainText("File input: " + fileInput + "\n" + "Method: " + methodChosen + "\n" + "Target Process: " + targetProcess + "\n" + "PID: " + dwordToQstring + "\n" + "INJECTED");
            qDebug() << "LastDLL=>" << dllPath << "\n";
            qDebug() << &pDllPath;
            qDebug() << GetLastError();

            VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, pDllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_RELEASE); // free the memory allocated for out dll
         }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried a lot of solutions only a few different conversion techniques, but they didn't change anything, any idea on what is causing this weird output?.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thought I had fixed it but it seems to occur completely randomly sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't really confused.

Comment: `dllPath = fileInput.toStdString().c_str();` looks wrong. Thats creating a temp `std::string` then storing the const char* out of it, then the temp string gets destroyed.

Comment: @MikeVine Thanks for the reply, what would be the work around for this?
would something like this be sufficient `LPCSTR dllPath = 0;
    QString dwordToQstring;
    std::string dllToString;

    QString fileInput = ui->filesCmb->currentText();    //gets dll
    dllToString = fileInput.toStdString();
    dllPath = dllToString.c_str();`

Comment: Please show output of setPlainText `File input:...` line.